# Php readfile() not working to read pdf on mobiles

Tags: php, pdf, mobile

I'm making a page with two buttons download and read to either read or download the pdf files. The php code is working fine when I check on laptops and tablets but when it comes to cell phones the download button works but read button does not. It gives the following error.

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf: "http://localhost/client1/download.php".

I've searched a lot and found that this is a chrome bug which was removed in version 40 . I downloaded it but the error still persists.

```
   header( 'Content-type: application/pdf' );
   header( 'Content-Disposition: inline' );
   header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );
   header( 'Accept-Ranges: bytes' );
   @readfile( $file->link );
```

Comment: Is there a problem with headers send by PHP? How do you set them? Please add it in your question, as it's written it's hard to help you without seeing any code.

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with php headers as it is working fine for desktop , laptops and even tablets .Its not working for cell phones.

Comment: So this question is not really about PHP but much rather about buggy client implementations. Perhaps you want to elaborate a little more on the (mobile-)browsers you have tested and add the appropriate tags to your question?

Comment: I used the php tag as I think that there is an issue with the php code . I don't know much about php as I'm new to it.

Comment: Is it specific to a phone model or to the Chrome version?

Comment: I think you are not getting my point I'm using chrome's inspect element to evaluate whether my page is responsive or not and whether its buttons work or not. Buttons are fine for laptops of all types and tablets even but read button does not work for mobile of even a single kind. I hope you've got my point now. Sorry for not being elaborative @A.L

Comment: So you are actually testing it on a resized desktop browser?